# How to retrieve the value from an array table in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I created an array table but want to retrieve the second value based on the first value.

For the below table, basically I want to have if animal is cow, show me "moo"; if it's dinosaur, show me "roar"...

```
ARRAY=( "cow:moo"
        "dinosaur:roar"
        "bird:chirp"
        "bash:rock" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an associative array instead.

```
$ declare -A array
$ array=([cow]=moo [dinosaur]=roar [bird]=chirp [bash]=rock)
$ echo "${array[cow]}"
moo
```

You can generate the above from your original automatically:

```
old_array=( "cow:moo" "dinosaur:roar" "bird:chirp" "bash:rock" )
declare -A array
for x in "${old_array[@]}"; do
  IFS=: read key value <<< "$x"
  # Or
  # key=${x%%:*}
  # value=${x#*:}
  array[$key]=$value
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to refactor and use parallel arrays.

```
animal=( cow dinosaur bird )
sound=( moo road chirp )
for ndx in "${!animal[@]}"
do echo "${animal[ndx]}: ${sound[ndx]}"
done
cow: moo
dinosaur: road
bird: chirp
```

Or as chepner said, use an associative array -

```
declare -A sound=(
   [cow]=moo
   [dinosaur]=roar
   [bird]=chirp
)
for critter in "${!sound[@]}"
do echo "$critter: ${sound[$critter]}"
done  # note that these will be unordered
dinosaur: roar
cow: moo
bird: chirp
```

I'd use the associative.